# Is it possible to hard-link local git submodule repositories?

Tags: git, git-submodules

We currently have a fairly large git repository with submodules (about 10GB), and cloning it from the server takes quite some time. I want to keep a local copy in our project directory and use it as the origin for builds. The project directory is stored on an NFS-mounted drive.

Git makes hard links to the original repository when cloning with --local or just /path/to/repo, but it does not seem to make hard links for the submodule repos. I would have expected

```
git clone --local --recursive /path/to/origin mycopy
```

to create hard links for all repos. Can I tell git to use hard links for the submodules too?

Comment: how is the path to the submodules specified?

Comment: As far as I can see, just "sub1", "sub2 etc. The sub1/.git file looks like this: gitdir: ../.git/modules/sub1

Comment: post the contents of `.git/config`, please

Comment: Additionally: the "path" is "sub1", but the clone's submodule URL is actually the origin's remote URL (eg ssh://...) so it probably downloads the data from the remote server, instead of copying in the file system(?).

Comment: @Gunnar That would make sense.  If the submodule has an SSH url git has no way of knowing the file system path is to the same place.  You could modify the urls in your local `.gitmodules` and `.git/config` and see what happens.

Comment: Perhaps clone the submodules with `--local` too?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done with a buildin command, but you can modify the `.gitmodules` file before the `git submodule init` (or equivalent) command and restore the original later:

```
git clone --local /path/to/origin mycopy
sed -i '/path = /{h;s,.* = ,,;x};/url = /{s, = .*, = /path/to/origin,;G;s,\n,,}' mycopy/.gitmodules
git -C mycopy submodule update --init
git -C mycopy checkout -- .gitmodules
```